# Java logic in my code

Tags: java, logic, runtime-error

Okay, so I have this code below and I keep getting run-time errors and I'm thinking its a flaw in the codes logic. I'm trying to use the `setOneOtherPicture` method to pick a picture and set it into an array to be later called on to be displayed in the `showArtCollection` method. I've been given two parameters, `which` and `pRef`. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

```
  public class House
{
 String owner;
 Picture pRef;
 Picture favPic;
 Picture [] picArray = new Picture [3];

public void showArtCollection ()
  {

  ArtWall aWall = new ArtWall(600,600);
  aWall.copyPictureIntoWhere(favPic,250,100);
  aWall.copyPictureIntoWhere(pRef,51,330);
  aWall.copyPictureIntoWhere(pRef,151,330);
  aWall.copyPictureIntoWhere(pRef,351,280);

  aWall.show();

 }

public void setOneOtherPicture (int which, Picture pRef)
 {

 this.picArray [which] = new Picture (FileChooser.pickAFile ());
 }

  public static void main (String [] args)
   {
     House PhDsHouse = new House ("Mad PH.D.");
     Picture favPic = new Picture ();
     Picture pRef = new Picture ();
     PhDsHouse.setOneOtherPicture (0, pRef);
     PhDsHouse.setOneOtherPicture (1, pRef);
     PhDsHouse.setOneOtherPicture (2,pRef);
     PhDsHouse.showArtCollection ();
   }
```

Comment: What exceptions? Please post the entire Exception message. What lines of code are involved? The exception message should tell you this, and you will then have to indicate this to us via a comment in your code or something similar.

Comment: This question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377626/nonstatic-variable-pref-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context/16378457#16378457

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @Bill: it has to be homework. I wonder if we have one user with two identities? That's not a good thing and the mods if they find this out can ban both.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry, I forgot one bit of code, I just fixed it now. Its giving me a nullPointerException on 'PhDsHouse.setOneOtherPicture (0, pRef);'

Comment: @Bill its a piece of a code that I've been working on for class. Not the whole thing of course. I just was stuck on this one problem for literally hours!

Comment: @Bill http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179064/i-couldnt-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-with-no-upvoted-answer

Answer (score 1):

Your `House` class has several fields, and your `main` method has local variables with the same names.  Perhaps these should be sent into the constructor?  Otherwise, these fields are null, which causes the crash in the `showArtHouse` method.

Answer (score 0):

this method:

```
public void setOneOtherPicture (int which, Picture pRef)
{
 this.picArray [which] = new Picture (FileChooser.pickAFile ());
}
```

shouldn't be calling FileChooser, and it shouldn't even be creating a *new* Picture object, but instead should just be putting pRef Picture object that you already have passed into the method into the array. Otherwise you're just throwing the pRef parameter away -- makes no sense.